# docker compose not working

Tags: 20.04, docker

I have Ubuntu 20.04 WSL 2 Linux subsystem running and I cloned the [following repo](https://github.com/docksal/boilerplate-drupal-gatsby) and ran `fin init` as mentioned in the ReadMe. However, I am getting the following error:

```
tan@JupiterComputer:~/docksal_test/boilerplate-drupal-gatsby$ fin init
 WARNING:  '.docksal' base domain and local DNS resolver are deprecated
           Please update your Docksal and project configuration
           See https://docs.docksal.io/stack/configuration-variables/#docksal-dns-disabled
 WARNING:  '.docksal' base domain and local DNS resolver are deprecated
           Please update your Docksal and project configuration
           See https://docs.docksal.io/stack/configuration-variables/#docksal-dns-disabled
Removing resources...

Usage:  docker compose [OPTIONS] COMMAND

Docker Compose

Options:
      --ansi string                Control when to print ANSI control characters ("never"|"always"|"auto") (default "auto")
      --compatibility              Run compose in backward compatibility mode
      --env-file stringArray       Specify an alternate environment file.
  -f, --file stringArray           Compose configuration files
      --parallel int               Control max parallelism, -1 for unlimited (default -1)
      --profile stringArray        Specify a profile to enable
      --project-directory string   Specify an alternate working directory
                                   (default: the path of the, first specified, Compose file)
  -p, --project-name string        Project name

Commands:
  build       Build or rebuild services
  config      Parse, resolve and render compose file in canonical format
  cp          Copy files/folders between a service container and the local filesystem
  create      Creates containers for a service.
  down        Stop and remove containers, networks
  events      Receive real time events from containers.
  exec        Execute a command in a running container.
  images      List images used by the created containers
  kill        Force stop service containers.
  logs        View output from containers
  ls          List running compose projects
  pause       Pause services
  port        Print the public port for a port binding.
  ps          List containers
  pull        Pull service images
  push        Push service images
  restart     Restart service containers
  rm          Removes stopped service containers
  run         Run a one-off command on a service.
  start       Start services
  stop        Stop services
  top         Display the running processes
  unpause     Unpause services
  up          Create and start containers
  version     Show the Docker Compose version information

Run 'docker compose COMMAND --help' for more information on a command.
unknown docker command: "compose compose"
```

What might be the reason behind unknown docker command here?

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu! Given just the information you've provided, it seems that somewhere there is a `docker compose compose` being issued, which is causing the issue. Take a look at the commands that are being called and make sure there aren't any with duplicate `compose` instructions in place.